# Помогите найти и исправить ошибку

Tags: c#

Написал код, вот только при любом раскладе ответ 0.

> Определите значение функции F. Предусмотрите вывод сообщения о том, по какой ветви происходило вычисление:
>
> - F = max(x, y + sqrt(x)) при x > 0, y ≥ 0,
> - F = min(sin<sup>2</sup>x, cosy<sup>2</sup>) при x < 0,
> - F = 0,5x + e<sup>y</sup> иначе.

```
        double x;
        double y;
        double e = 0;
        double min = 0;
        double max = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Введите y");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        y = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        Console.WriteLine("Введите x");
        string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        x = Convert.ToDouble(s1);
        if (x > 0 && y>=0)
        {
            x = max * (x * y + Math.Sqrt(x));
            Console.WriteLine("Вычисление производилось по первой ветви");
        }
        else if (x < 0)
        {
            x = min * (Math.Sin(Math.Pow(x,2)) * (Math.Cos(Math.Pow(x, 2))));
            Console.WriteLine("Вычисление производилось по второй ветви");
        }
        else
        {
            x = 0.5*x + Math.Pow(e,y);
            Console.WriteLine("Вычисление производилось по третей ветви");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Ответ: " + x);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Так у вас значения e, min, max - НОЛЬ. Очевидно, что в результате вычислений ноль и получится. P.S. А отладчиком совсем пользоваться не умеете, да? Проще у людей спросить, чем самому проверить что и как вычисляется?

Comment: и `double e = 0;` глаза режет и это ещё мягко сказано. Кстати 3 ветка ещё может что-то посчитать вот только не то что вы хотите.

Comment: @PinkTux спасибо. Нет, не умею, да здравствует наша система образования! Никто даже и не думал рассказывать об отладчике.

Comment: @pavel, что она может посчитать?

Comment: @Mars, если вы "учите" только то, что "рассказывают" - вам просто нечего делать в программировании. Не тратьте своё и чужое время.

Comment: @Mars: Немедленно учите! Крэш-курс: F10 выполняет одну строку, F11 то же самое но с заходом внутрь функций, мышкой по вертикальной границе слева можно ставить точку останова (появится бордовая точка), F5 запускает программу бежать до точки останова. В окне Watch (найдите его!) можно смотреть значения переменных. Давайте, пробуйте.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо большое. Посидел, поэкспериментировал, начинаю разбираться.

Comment: @Mars: Очень хорошо! Отладка очень важна, программист процентов 50, а то и 70 времени проводит в отладке. Написать работающий с первого раза код нереально сложно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Значение экспоненты у вас 0, а должна быть правильная математическая константа
2. min, max - это не множители а функции, max(a,b) - возвращает больше из a и b, min - меньшее... У вас не правильно интерпретирована формула в первых 2 ветвях.

2.1. min, max принимает 2 аргумента, в формуле через запятую в программе вы их перемножили

Comment: 1. Константа не нужна, а нужно использовать `Math.Exp(y)`.

Comment: Это бесспорно, ровно как и необходимость правильно использовать остальные математические функции. Например Math.Sin(Math.Pow(x,2)) это sin(x^2), когда по условию задачи должно быть  sin^2(x).

Comment: Хорошо подмечено!

Comment: Значит, нужно записать как-то так: 
`x = min(Math.Sin(Math.Pow(x, 2)),(Math.Cos(Math.Pow(x, 2))));`? Но на такой код ругается

Comment: @Mars: А вы посмотрите, как именно в языке кодируется минимум. Математическая нотация — это одно, а язык программирования может те же операции обозначать по-разному. Например, вместо `sin` в C# используется `Math.Sin`.

Comment: @VladD читал о минимумах в C#, но не совсем все понял

Comment: @Mars: Ну `Math.Min` же!

Comment: @VladD, ох, точно, получилось. Я пробовал раньше, но была ошибка, как оказалась, забыл про запятые. Так стыдно. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Mars: Не знать не стыдно, стыдно не учиться. А вы как раз чему-то научились, так что повода для стыда нету.

Comment: @Mars: Будьте внимательны с формулами. У вас 2 ветка это sin квадрат от агрумента и cos от квадрата аргумента. Практически всегда в математике это важно :)